# How to convert to a GST date?

Tags: java, date

After doing a lot of google research I am posting this question here in this expert group.
I have found many related links but did not work in my case.

I am fetching a date value from database which comes in this format **2016-01-12 00:00:00.0**. Now I want to compare this date with the date what user is entering from screen UI which comes in this format **Thu Jan 13 00:00:00 GST 2016**.

Now I want to compare these dates i.e. the date which was entered from screen (Thu Jan 13 00:00:00 GST 2016) should not be greater the or equal to the date fetched from the DB (2016-01-12 00:00:00.0).

For date comparing I am using:

```
public static boolean compareDates(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {

    if (fromDate.before(toDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which is not working because date format is not similar what I feel.

So I want to convert 2016-01-12 00:00:00.0  to  Thu Jan 12 00:00:00 GST 2016.

Please help me in this as I am stucked since morning in this issue.
If you have any other solution to compare these dates, kindly suggest me.

I am calling the method compareDates(Date fromDate, Date toDate) from my bean class like this :

```
if (!TeltrackDateUtil.compareDates( installationdate, instrumentStaffLnkData.getEffectiveFrom() )) {

String erroMessage = resourceBundle .getString("instrument_add_edit_mandatory_check_linkage_effective_from_ins‌​tallation_date");
 createFacesMessage(erroMessage, facesContext); canProceed = false; 
}
```

in this `installationdate = 2016-01-12 00:00:00.0` (from database) and `instrumentStaffLnkData.getEffectiveFrom() = Thu Jan 14 00:00:00 GST 2016` which is from screen.

Adding some additional code:

In the DB (Oracle SQL developer), it is stored as `datetime`, in my Entity class it is `Timestamp effectiveFrom`.

In my `ServiceImpl` class I am setting this into a TO class variable :

`InstrumentTO instrument = setEffectiveFrom(instrumentEntity.getEffectiveFrom());`

Finally in bean class :

```
InstrumentTO instrument = instrumentService.getSelectedInstrument(instrumentId);
instrumentStaffLnkData.setInstrument(instrument); 
Date installationdate = instrumentStaffLnkData.getInstrument().getEffectiveFrom();
```

and then calling `compareDates()`.

Comment: Any problem in *this method* is not caused by date formatting, since `Date` has no formatting - it is just an instant in time. It is in the code which parses your strings into dates. Please post that.

Comment: BTW: your method body can be written more concisely (and idiomatically) as `return fromDate.before(toDate)`. Mind you, calls to this method like `YourClassName.compareDates(fromDate, toDate)` would also be more concisely written as `fromDate.before(toDate)` - the method doesn't add anything over just calling that directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andy. So you means to say I can directly use the method compareDates() by passing those two dates directly ?

Comment: Andy, I am calling compareDates(Date fromDate, Date toDate) from my bean class like this :    if (!TeltrackDateUtil.compareDates(
     installationdate,
     instrumentStaffLnkData.getEffectiveFrom()
     )) {
    String erroMessage = resourceBundle
      .getString("instrument_add_edit_mandatory_check_linkage_effective_from_installation_date");
    createFacesMessage(erroMessage, facesContext);
    canProceed = false;
   }  in this installationdate = 2016-01-12 00:00:00.0 (from database) and instrumentStaffLnkData.getEffectiveFrom() = Thu Jan 14 00:00:00 GST 2016  which is from screen. Thanks

Comment: Please post relevant code in your question. It is impossible to read in comments.

Comment: It's likely your two dates are instantiated using different classes, for example `java.sql.Timestamp` rather than `java.util.Date` your update as per Andy's comments doesn't tell us how you're parsing the values from the database into code.

Comment: The only relevant code you need to show is how you are converting the strings `"2016-01-12 00:00:00.0"` and `"Thu Jan 14 00:00:00 GST 2016"` into `Date` instances.

Comment: Dear Andy and Khan, In DB(Oracle SQL developer), it is stored as 'datetime', in my Entity class it is  'Timestamp effectiveFrom'. In my ServiceImpl class I am setting this into a TO class variable :  **InstrumentTO instrument = setEffectiveFrom(instrumentEntity.getEffectiveFrom());**   Finally in bean class :   ** InstrumentTO instrument = instrumentService
      .getSelectedInstrument(instrumentId);
    instrumentStaffLnkData.setInstrument(instrument);
    
    Date installationdate = instrumentStaffLnkData.getInstrument().getEffectiveFrom(); **  and then calling compareDates() as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse your two different formats to date objects like this:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date dateFromDatabase = df.parse("2016-01-12 00:00:00.0");

    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date dateFromUi = df2.parse("Thu Jan 12 00:00:00 GST 2016");

    compareDates(dateFromDatabase, dateFromUi);
```

But generally I would recommend you to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for the reason @Srikanta has explained in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Opt for JodaTime library if you are using Java 7 or less. In Java 8, you can use the Time API. These libraries allow you to switch between the time formats including the time zones. There by making it easier to compare.